# Possible pointer invalidation using std::vectors (corrupted size vs. prev_size)

Tags: c++, std

I am building a C++ app that needs to create an array of structures that must point to raw memory addresses (void * + size_t). In order to keep the values (std::vector<uint8_t>) on the stack I am using another standard vector (std::vectorstd::vector<uint8_t>). With this approach I am getting an exception (corrupted size vs. prev_size). I think the the data() pointer is being invalidated.

I create this example that is similar to my code. If you could let me known the error and/or tell me another alternative to keep the data on the scope it will be awesome.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int fill_vector(std::vector<uint8_t> &t_vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Here a value is copied (this is an example)
        t_vec.push_back(0x01);
    }
}

struct SContainer
{
    void *data;
    size_t size;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> t_vec_vals;
    std::vector<uint8_t> t_vec_val;
    std::vector<SContainer> t_vec_containers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fill_vector(t_vec_val);
        // Keep filled vector on the scope
        t_vec_vals.push_back(t_vec_val);
        SContainer c;
        c.data = t_vec_vals[i].data();
        c.size = t_vec_vals[i].size();
        t_vec_containers.push_back(c);
    }

    // Use t_vec_containers data
    // Exception:
    // corrupted size vs. prev_size
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `fill_vector` promises to return and `int`, but does not. You should eliminate this bit of Undefined  Behaviour before you investigate further.

Comment: Probably a really good idea to expand on `// Use t_vec_containers data`. What you are currently showing doesn't reproduce the reported problem before or after I fix the obvious mistakes.

Comment: That said, you're almost certainly correct. The `push_back`s to `t_vec_vals` will be invalidating the pointers in `t_vec_containers` to `t_vec_vals` stored data.

Comment: @user4581301 Seems like when `t_tec_vals` grows the individual `std::vector<uint8_t>` elements' `data()` shouldn't be invalidated.

Comment: The code seems to run correctly when I try it : https://godbolt.org/z/a6nh6nY1P The problem is likely in the `// Use t_vec_containers data` part that is omitted.

Comment: Assuming everything C++11 or better, I'd expect the data buffers to be moved and stay the same the whole way through, but I don't think I can guarantee that. Going to loot the code, tweak it, and see what happens.

Comment: @user4581301 I think its guaranteed. Resizing uses move semantics if it is available is `noexcept` which is true for `std::vector`. And from [`std::vector::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) *"After container move construction (overload (8)), references, pointers, and iterators (other than the end iterator) to other remain valid, but refer to elements that are now in *this."*

Comment: And some simple practical abuse backs that up at least back to GCC 5. Use of `uint8_t` suggests C++11, but it could be coming in from a C99 header.

Comment: `>>` in the templates more strongly suggests C++11, so OK. I'm convinced. Bug is definitely in `// Use t_vec_containers data`

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

So one problem with vector is all the storage is in 1 continuous block. Each time you resize it, the storage is reallocated and is very likely to move.

Therefore, the address of the first element in t_vec_vals is unlikely to be a safe value, once further elements are pushed into it.

If you were to use a std::list for t_vec_val, then the individual elements are individually allocated, and do not move until deleted.

Another option is to reserve the vector to the size you expect to use.

Comment: The code doesn't take a pointer to an element in `t_vec_vals`. It uses pointers to the result of `data()` for its elements. Growing `t_vec_vals` shouldn't cause its elements' data to be invalidated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm you might be right. But perhaps in moving the vectors they are reallocating their buffers. Shouldn't happen because they should be able to use move semantics. It doesn't actually say c++11 though, so perhaps it predates std::move? Surely not!

Comment: I'm going to leave the answer up for now, because it is a line of enquiry if all else fails.